# WooCommerce change fields order at 'add product' page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i have a WooCommerce site and i need to change the order of the input fields when adding new product. 'The Short Description' should be first and the main description should come right after.

I've tried to edit wp-admin/edit-form-advanced.php and i did found the divs but if im switching their order it's getting all messed up..

Maybe i'm editing the wrong file? anyone have experience with it?

Thanks

Comment: Just drag & drop metabox in `add-new-product` page in `wp-admin` and set your order...That would be possible..

Comment: Yes i tried that but the entire form is messing up and i couldn't fix it